# JavaScript - Is it possible to record audio and upload it simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, stream, observable

In my app users can record themselves using microphone, and then upload recording to the server. Is it technically possible to upload this audio file while they are recording themselves?

Comment: Yes, it is. Ever had a phone call?

Comment: Ok, but how is it possible? What should I know and learn about it?

Comment: I... suppose so. But you will probably need to write your own net code. Have a request mark the beginning, the end, and continuous stream for bytes in the middle. The server has to somehow put it together. But it may not be all that fast. Perhaps there are JS VoIP frameworks? Why do you need to do this, may I ask?

Comment: Wonder what are you using in order to accomplish that. Is it just plain JS running on a browser ?

Comment: I'm also running a Nodejs server. What I want to do is to send this audio file as seperate chunks to the backend, every 2seconds (just an example). And then when I'm done sending chunks, backend needs to concatenate somehow those chunks into one file. I'm not sure if this is possible, but from what I read it is. Learning about blobs/multipart form data etc